# How to send a file to a ASMX web service using VB6?

Tags: wcf, file-upload, vb6, asmx, cloud

I have a VB6 application that I want to provide my users a feature where they can backup their data file to the cloud.  I have a system in place where they can upload a file to the cloud and store it, now I want to make it a little easier by a menu option.  File..Backup to Cloud would create a zip archive of the database (Access 97 MDB) and then send the byte array to an ASMX (or WCF) web service.

Can someone share with me how to take a file (500 KB to 1.5 MB on average), in VB6, and send it to an ASMX web service?  I need to be "firewall friendly" so keep that in mind as well, so something across Port 80 (HTTP) is preferred.

Comment: Wow. Makes a lot of sense to add new features to a VB6 application. Are you aware that VB6 is totally unsupported? See http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2971

Comment: John, it's irrelevant what's unsupported, it's relevant to support legacy applications until their replacements are ready.

Comment: "support legacy applications" is one thing. "Continue to extend them using obsolete and unsupported technologies" is another. If the application is important enough to your organization that you add functionality to it, then surely it's important enough to be built on a supported platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 supports COM components. You should be doing your new development by creating COM components in a .NET language (for instance, VB.NET or C#), and having your VB6 application call them. That way, you get the benefit of using software developed using modern tools, but you get to call them from your obsolete and unsupported VB6 code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WinHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) object.

[VBA/Corel Draw: How to send binary and text file in HTTP POST request to server from VBA/VB6 script running from Corel Draw 12/X4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946603/vba-corel-draw-how-to-send-binary-and-text-file-in-http-post-request-to-server-f)

[Post Method + WinHttpRequest + multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885703/vb6-post-method-winhttprequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Not very convenient unless the service uses HTTP.